# Tab Bar Lost When Switching Views

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have two views that are embedded inside `navigationController`s. One of these views is also embedded inside a `tabController`.

When I switch back and forth between the two views, I lose the `tabBar` that was originally on one of the views.

What is the best way to go about fixing this issue? I am currently using a `segue` at the moment and am at a loss.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change my navigation controller to be the root view controller, or have the tab bar segue go to the navigation view controller first

Comment: I just edited the image link to show my storyboard with the tab bar controller. Am I following your advice correctly?

Comment: Actually I only saw a partial view of the image previously. So my advise may not have been accurate. Sorry. Much better now, I see the full image. Could you write down the exact scenario? Step by step what you are tapping on? Also, I am curious as to why you have another navigation controller from the Profile view controller

Comment: The profile view controller has a navigation controller because I have a right  bar button that segues to settings view controller - this view also has a navigation controller because I have a left bar button that segues back to the profile view controller. The tab bar is missing when I segue from settings view controller -> profile view controller.

Comment: You don't need the the second navigation. The one you already have before Profile gives you the back button on Settings automatically when you segue to it from Profile. Try removing it.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But if I may ask one more question - why is the back button invisible? I've investigated the issue and I've tried the following solutions with no luck. I tried adding a title to the Profile page in viewDidAppear(). I also have the segue set as Show, and I named it a custom identifier.

Comment: I am not really sure, but you may have some views (button etc..) on the "Page" that are covering it up.