# How to place a tab bar when coming back from navigation controller to home?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a tab bar controller on home page and there is a side menu also on it on side menu.

I am having view controllers like this

[image]

when i click on any one of the side menu view controllers it was working but when coming back from the side menu navigation controllers tab bar was missing and title was also missing.

Can any one help me how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666399/8363795).

The navigation controller view should be the root view.